# inside single view create form as well as display data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a view page where I need to display data and as well as a form to insert data. To insert data I have bootstrap modal. How can I bind my view page so that I can have data to display in the page as well as create form to insert data. I mean how can I bind my view to display data?

```
public ActionResult GetFirm()
        {
            return View(db.FirmModels.ToList());
        }
```

My view page

```
@model models.FirmModel

// code for bootstrap modal
// code for data table
<table id="tblFirmData">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Edit/Print</th>
            <th style="visibility:hidden;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirmId)</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>CONTACT</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach(var item in models)
        {
            int status = item.FirmRegistrationStatus;
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I do `foreach(var item in models)` getting error `'models' is a namespace but is used like a variable`  and when I do `@foreach(var item in Model)` I am getting error `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'FirmModel' because 'FirmModel' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'`.

How to solve this problem, shall I need to modify my `GetFirm` return method or need to change in view page?

Answer (score 0):

Because of you pass a list to the view define you view model as:

```
@model IEnumerable<models.FirmModel>
```

The `IEnumerable` interface is implementing the `GetEnumerator()` method used to iterate through the collection.

Or:

```
@model IList<models.FirmModel>
```

The [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=netframework-4.8) interface inherits the `IEnumerable`.

And correspondingly:

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{    
    ....
}
```